# Caching property og php

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the properties from a link like facebook does only the page loses many seconds to load with a couple of links. Is there any way to speed it up? For example using caches?

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$c = file_get_contents('https://link-here');
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:title']") as $el) {
    $title = $el->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:description']") as $el) {
    $content = $el->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:image']") as $el) {
    $image = $el->getAttribute("content");
}
```